# Rails Omniauth twitter gem - not authorizing user correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, twitter, devise, omniauth

I'm building a Rails app which allows users to create and book onto events. I've integrated the twitter omniauth gem along with devise. It logs me in correctly and redirects back however when I click on the link to create an event or book an event the app redirects me back to the sign in page. I've set the site up so that only signed in users can do this but it doesn't appear to cover the omniauth integration.
I also have no way to sign-out from one user to another if I use Twitter to sign in. I want to add Facebook auth also but want to fix this first. What code (inc. validations) am I missing to cover these functions?

Here's the relevant code so far -

Events Controller -

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,]
# the before_actions will take care of finding the correct event for us
# this ties in with the private method below
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
# this ensures only users who are signed in can alter an event

def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @events = Event.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @events = Event.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    # The above code = If there's no category found then all the events are listed
    # If there is then it will show the EVENTS under each category only
end

def show
end

def new
    @event = current_user.events.build
    # this now builds out from a user once devise gem is added
    # after initially having an argument of Event.new
    # this assigns events to users
end
# both update and create actions below use event_params as their argument with     an if/else statement 
def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    # as above this now assigns events to users
    # rather than Event.new

    if @event.save
        redirect_to @event, notice: "Congratulations, you have successfully created a new event."
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    # edit form
    # @edit = Edit.find(params[:id])
    @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if @event.update(event_params)
        redirect_to @event, notice: "Event was successfully updated!"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :location, :date, :time, :description, :number_of_spaces, :is_free, :price, :organised_by, :url, :image, :category_id)
    # category_id added at the end to ensure this is assigned to each new event created
end

def find_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end







end
```

Application controller -

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected 

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name

  end

  # the application controller
  # handles everything across the site

  # make the current_user AND the logged_in? available to
  # be used in the views as well as the controllers
  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :logged_in?
  helper_method :logged_out?

  def current_user
    # this is who I am signed in as
    @current_user = User.find(session[:uid])
  end

  def logged_in?
    # am i logged in?
    # do i have a cookie called uid?
    session[:uid].present?
  end

  def make_sure_logged_in
    # If I'm not logged in, redirect me to the log in page
    if not logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be signed in to see that page"
      redirect_to new_session_path
    end
  end

  def logged_out?
    session[:uid] = nil
    flash[:success] = "You've logged out"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

index.html.erb - events

```
<header>
<div class="category">

        <%= link_to  image_tag('MamaKnows.png'), root_path, id: "home" %>
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
                <li><%= link_to category.name, events_path(category: category.name) %></li>
                    <% end %>
                    <!-- The code loop above creates category links to the home page -->



</div>
<nav id="nav">

    <% if logged_in? %>
            <%= link_to 'Create Event', new_event_path %>
            <%= link_to 'Account', user_path(current_user) %>
            <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Create an Event", new_user_session_path %>
        <% end %>           

</nav>      
</header>   

<% @events.each do |event| %>


<%= link_to (image_tag event.image.url), event %>

<h2><%= link_to event.title, event %></h2>
<h2><%= link_to event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y'), event %></h2>

<% end %>
```

OmniauthCallback Controller

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def twitter

     @details = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

    @provider = @details["provider"]
    @provider_id = @details["uid"]

    @user = User.where(provider: @provider, provider_id: @provider_id).first

    if @user.present?
        #sign them in
    else
        # make a new user
        @user = User.new
        @user.provider = @provider
        @user.provider_id = @provider_id

        # because of has_secure_password - will this work?
        @user.password = "AAAAAA!!"
        @user.password_confirmation = "AAAAAA!!"

        # let's save the key and secret
        @user.key = @details["credentials"]["token"]
        @user.secret = @details["credentials"]["secret"]

        # lets fill in their details
        @user.name = @details["info"]["name"]
        if @provider == "twitter"? @user.save!(:validate => false) : @user.save!
        # the above if statement allows for twitter to skip validation which requires an email
        @user.email = @details["info"]["email"]
        end

        @user.save!
    end


        session[:uid] = @user.id 
        flash[:success] = "You've signed in"
        redirect_to root_path

end


def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
end






end
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.